# Scraping links from html elements - casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am currently trying to scrape links and thumbnails from this [SITE](http://video.wired.com/) with the help of casperjs. I was able to easily figure out the html structure(shown below). I am trying to extract from all `a` tags the link found in the `href` attribute. I run my script but I get an error for `video_links` . How could I go about scraping all links and thumbnails and output in an array?
Error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'video_links.length')
```

Script

```
var casper = require('casper').create({}),video_links,video_thumbnails;

//Functions
function getLinks() {
    var element = document.querySelectorAll('.cne-episode-block a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(element, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href');
    });
}
casper.start('http://video.wired.com/');

casper.then(function() {
    video_links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});

casper.run( this.echo(video_links.length + ' links found.') );
```

HTML

```
<div class="cne-thumb-grid-container cne-context-container">
    <div class="cne-thumb cne-episode-block " data-videoid="551dc13461646d11aa020000">
        <div class="cne-thumb-image cne-rollover" data-powertiptarget="551dc13461646d11aa020000">
            <a class="cne-thumbnail cne-zoom-effect js-ajax-video-load" href="/watch/angry-nerd-will-netflix-s-daredevil-fly-or-flop" data-video-series="Angry Nerd" data-video-series-id="518d55c268f9dac897000003" data-video-id="551dc13461646d11aa020000" data-video-categories="[" Movies \u0026 TV "]">
                <img class="cne-video-thumb" src="http://dwgyu36up6iuz.cloudfront.net/heru80fdn/image/upload/c_fill,d_placeholder_thescene.jpg,fl_progressive,g_face,h_151,q_80,w_270/v1428076783/wired_angry-nerd-will-netflix-s-daredevil-fly-or-flop.jpg" alt="Will Netflixâ€™s Daredevil Fly or Flop?">
                <div class="cne-thumbnail-play">Play</div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="cne-thumb-title the-thumb-title">
            <a class="js-ajax-video-load" href="/watch/angry-nerd-will-netflix-s-daredevil-fly-or-flop" data-video-id="551dc13461646d11aa020000">Will Netflixâ€™s Daredevil Fly or Flop?</a>
            <div class="cne-thumb-subtitle">
                <a href="/series/angry-nerd">Angry Nerd</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="551dc13461646d11aa020000" class="cne-thumb-rollover">
            <div class="cne-thumb-rollover-box">
                <span class="cne-rollover-category"> Movies & TV </span>
                <span class="cne-rollover-name"> Will Netflixâ€™s Daredevil Fly or Flop? </span>
                <span class="cne-rollover-description"> If Netflixâ€™s new Daredevil series is anything like Ben Affleckâ€™s Daredevil film, weâ€™re all in trouble. Angry Nerd explains what the latest incarnation needs to get right to make sure the man without fear doesnâ€™t turn into a total flop. </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What error do you get? What is the expected behavior? Also, please edit your question to properly indent your code.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have indented and added the error currently displayed. The expected behavior is to show or indicate the links that were found.

Comment: Now you changed your code in such a way that it probably works. In any case, it seems you forgot a `.` for the selector before the last edit. Don't ever change your code in an invasive way when there is already an answer. I rolled back your edit. You may try again, to make it good.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes, it works now. Although it now displays another behavior that i didnt desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the selectors are on the same level, you will only need one of them. So just use either `cne-thumb` or `cne-episode-block` in your querySelectorAll not both.